# Dimensions too large in smooth decorated plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, dimensions

Why do I get a dimension too large error in the following example and how can I fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,decoration={
  markings,
  mark=
  between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm
  with
  {
  \draw (0,0) circle (1pt);
  }
},
postaction=decorate
  ] plot[smooth] coordinates {(1,4.5) (2,5) (7,4.5)};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Log:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-05-15>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecoration
s.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.markings.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./example.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.19 ...ooth] coordinates {(1,4.5) (2,5) (7,4.5)};
                                                  
?
```

**Edit:** Using the `hobby` options from the `hobby` library instead of `smooth` makes it work. But the quesion remains, why it doesn't work with `smooth`.

Comment: The decoration library wants to compute the transformation such that `(0,0)` is at a point on the curve, `(1,0)` is tangent to the curve at `(0,0)` and `(0,1)` is perpendicular. Doing so involves some heavy arithmetics and things just blow up if the constituent Bezier curves are too short.